# Rotation Matrix Given Initial Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Suppose we have two sets of orthonormal 16-dimensional vectors , ${x_1,...,x_4,x_5,..,x_8}$ and ${x_1',...,x_4'}$  with angle in-between $x_i$ and $x_i'$ being $\theta$ for 1<=i<=4. Is it possible to find a unitary matrix, $M$, for which $Mx_i = x_i'$ , and also the angle between $Mx_j$ and $x_j$ is $\theta$ for $5<= j<= 8$?

What would be an efficient algorithm to find such an $M$?

Of course, the number 16 and 4 and 8 can be generalized suitably and the answer should not change.

Comment: This sounds like the [orthogonal procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)

Comment: That said: as long as the number of dimensions is greater than the number of vectors, there is no problem (i.e. an "exact solution" exists). For any orthonormal sets of vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ and $w_1,\dots,w_k$ in $\Bbb C^n$ with $k \leq n$, there exists a unitary matrix $M$ for which $mv_j = w_j$ holds for all $j = 1,\dots,k$.  

For your problem, it then suffices to compute vectors $x_5',\dots,x_8'$ orthonormal to each other and $x_1',\dots,x_4'$ whose angles from $x_5,\dots,x_8$ are $\theta$, then find a unitary matrix $M$ for which $Mx_j = x_j'$ for $j = 1,\dots,8$.

Comment: Note that in $\Bbb C^n$, we can simultaneously rotate every vector by angle $\theta$ simply by multiplying by $e^{i \theta}$.